# Fatal error: Error raised at top level: failed to open file for writing

Tags: swift, macos

I want to test https://github.com/KarthikRIyer/swiftplot so I can use it in my project but I'm getting `Fatal error: Error raised at top level: failed to open file for writing` error that I can't understand well.

here is my code and what I tried (I know I have to implement good try catch but I want to test it first) :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftPlot
import AGGRenderer

let x:[Float] = [10,100,263,489]
let y:[Float] = [10,120,500,800]
let filePath = "/Users/ama25/Desktop/"
let fileName = "test"
let url = URL(string: filePath + "agg/" + fileName)

var agg_renderer: AGGRenderer = AGGRenderer()
var lineGraph = LineGraph<Float,Float>(enablePrimaryAxisGrid: true)
lineGraph.addSeries(x, y, label: "Plot 1", color: .lightBlue)
lineGraph.plotTitle.title = "SINGLE SERIES"
lineGraph.plotLabel.xLabel = "X-AXIS"
lineGraph.plotLabel.yLabel = "Y-AXIS"
lineGraph.plotLineThickness = 3.0
var output = try lineGraph.drawGraphAndOutput(fileName: fileName + "agg/" + fileName ,renderer: agg_renderer)

var data = Data(buffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &output, count: 1))
try data.write(to: url!)
```

The error:

```
Swift/ErrorType.swift:200: Fatal error: Error raised at top level: failed to open file for writing
```

The line of that gives the error:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`:
->  0x1977e1564 <+0>: ret
```

This is all the log that I'm getting and there is nothing more.

I have to note that everything is updated to latest release and I copied this code from `README` of the library and I modified it a little so I could see if I can fix it first. I'm trying to run it on macOS not iOS.

UPDATE: I tried turning off sandboxing and still I have this issue.

Comment: As mentioned in response to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78094022/1187415: `fileName + "agg/" + fileName` should probably be `filePath + "agg/" + fileName` .

Comment: @MartinR I fixed it but still same error. I tried multiple ways but still same error. It looks like macOS is not letting my app to write or read a file because of `safety or security`

Comment: That's not how you access a local file.  Besides, you aren't supposed to access a file at any location.  let url = URL(string: filePath + "agg/" + fileName)

Comment: @ElTomato so how can I get the output of it? I want to know how can I do it.

Comment: "It looks like macOS is not letting my app to write or read a file" Of course. You are sandboxed. Did you try turning off sandboxing?

Comment: @matt good call on that one. I will try it and then I will inform you.

Comment: @matt UPDATE on previous comment: no. it does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL(string:)` is the wrong API to create a file system URL from a path, it expects a string starting with a scheme,`file://` in this case.

The proper API is

```
URL(filePath:)
```

or to be compatible with systems prior to iOS 16/macOS 13

```
URL(fileURLWithPath:)
```

And also in iOS 16+ / macOS 13+ there is a shortcut to get the desktop directory of the current user

```
let desktopURL = URL.desktopDirectory
```

Further sandbox must be disabled to get `/Users/myself/Desktop`